# 403 Forbidden on requests

Tags: soundcloud

Is there some bug on SoundCloud api cause few days ago my software started to get 403 Forbidden statuses from SoundCloud api? Sometimes request is successful, but mostly get 403 status. Here is example, I'm trying to put like on a track:

Request:  /me/favorites/{track_id}.json?client_id={client_id}

Status: 403 Forbidden

Message which body is like this:

`<div id="maintenance">
      Whoa, something went wrong and it wasn't supposed to happen.
      <span>
        A <strong>report was sent</strong> to our tech team, they'll look into it.
        <br />
        Please check <a href="http://status.soundcloud.com/"><strong>our Status page</strong></a> for more details as they come in.
      </span>
    </div>`

Please help.

Comment: same problem here. I've also noticed that soundcloud is not accepting registration of new apps anymore: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfNxc82RJuzC0DnISat7n4H-G7IsPQIdaMpe202iiHZEoso9w/closedform

Comment: I've tried the exact same code with the tokens from a different application and it worked. Maybe Soundcloud is throttling or blocking some applications?

Answer (score -1):

You have provided the response from sound cloud, but not your full request. Which makes it hard to diagnose.

> Have you followed the API reference for follow/like tracks: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#follow

As a 403 is security related, and Sound Cloud clearly states:

> **Follow & Like**
>
> This section presumes you have:
>
> - Registered your App
> - Authenticated

If these calls previously worked, and now do not, please check you app registration within Sound Cloud ([Register your app](http://soundcloud.com/you/apps)) and that you have a current access token.

Sound Cloud uses OAuth 2.0 so make sure the authentication token you are using has not expired :)

Comment: For the reason you give in your first sentence, this question should not be answered at all. You should ask for more information in the comments and wait for that information instead. Otherwise, your answer is only a wild stab in the dark.

Comment: gotta give OP the benefit of the doubt, I could structure the response much better in an answer than in a comment. It's a good general response to anyone with 403 errors who may be new to soundcloud, or for that matter consuming any API. I was going to flag the question but realised that if I had enough information to make this judgement I'd look a bit silly for asking for more info and someone else would answer it anyway :)